# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined (on cloned html table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to export an HTML table to an excel file. Any hidden columns should not be exported.

The following works:

```
var table_div = document.getElementById('MyTable');
$(table_div).find('[style*="display: none"]').remove();

var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

but when I export, all the hidden columns get deleted from my table.

I tried cloning the table before removing the hidden columns:

```
var table_div = document.getElementById('MyTable');
var cloned_table_div = $(table_div).clone().find('[style*="display: none"]').remove();

var table_html = cloned_table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

but this gives an error in chrome "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined". I tried checking so see if cloned_table_div.outerHTML is undefined, and it seems it is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and native DOM APIs.

Comment: Your `cloned_table_div` don't have the table element and it is a jQuery element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315193/cannot-read-property-replace-of-undefined)

Comment: Just a little advice. The first thing you should do when your code doesn't run is to debug it. Here on stack overflow there is a special documentation of Javascript, both for advance users and for beginers. You should go an read the debugging section here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/642/debugging/10108/using-the-console (maybe first the console part only). This will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Functions `.find(...)` and `.remove()` don't return a cloned table. And they return a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), not an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).
2. To get an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) from a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), you should jQuery [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/).

```js
var table_div = document.getElementById('MyTable');
var cloned_table_div = $(table_div).clone();
cloned_table_div.find('[style*="display: none"]').remove();

var table_html = cloned_table_div.get(0).outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyTable">
    <span style="display: none"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Thanasis is correct. cloned_table_div is a jquery element.

There are 2 ways using which you can complete this task. 
One of them is to get the HTML from the jquery object like this

```
var table_div = document.getElementById('myTable');

$(table_div).clone().appendTo(".newTable");
console.log(cloned_table_div["0"].outerHTML)
```

second is appending the cloned data into a new div tag and then doing all that necessary action on that div tag. Something like this

```js
  var table_div = document.getElementById('myTable');
  $(table_div).clone().appendTo(".newTable");
  var newtable_div = document.getElementById('newTable');
  $(newtable_div).find('[style*="display:none"]').remove();
  newtable_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

  newtable_div.outerHTML = ""
```